# CUPS Printing with Brother MFCJ430W

Tags: raspbian-jessie, printing, cups

So I'm having trouble getting my printer to work, I installed CUPS and it seems to be working correctly. I downloaded and installed the drivers for the printer from the Brother website from here: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj430w_all

However, when I run the installer or try to print something using `lpr -P MFCJ430W /usr/share/cups/data/testprint` I get this error:

```
lpr: connect: No such file or directory
Is lpd daemon running?
jobs queued, but cannot start daemon.
```

When I run `sudo service lpd status` it shows active with the following errors

```
Mar 05 05:19:26 Nathan-Raspberry-Pi-1 lpd[1477]: MFCJ430W: filter 'f' 
exited (retcode=255 prog=/opt/brother/Printers/mfcj430w/lpd/filtermfcj430w)
Mar 05 05:19:26 Nathan-Raspberry-Pi-1 lpd[1477]: mail sent to user user about job testprint on printer MFCJ430W (FILTERERR)
```

If I try to print something using `lp -d MFCJ430W ~/testFile.txt`
I get `request id is MFCJ430W-42 (1 file(s))` but nothing prints. Also, nothing prints from the CUPS webpage.

My printer is connected via USB and I'm running Raspbian Jessie. Has anyone had this before or  fixed it? Note: i'm not running on the default user pi, but I have sudo privileges. Thanks, any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: This is how I run the installer and what it returns up to the the point of the error:

> user@Nathan-Raspberry-Pi-1:~ $ sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1
>   [sudo] password for user: 
>   Input model name ->mfcj430w
>
> You are going to install following packages.
>     mfcj430wlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb
>     mfcj430wcupswrapper-3.0.0-1.i386.deb
>     brscan4-0.4.4-3.i386.deb
>     brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.i386.deb
>   OK? [y/N] ->y
>
> dpkg -x mfcj430wlpr-3.0.1-1.i386.deb /
>   dpkg -x mfcj430wcupswrapper-3.0.0-1.i386.deb /
>   (Reading database ... 47006 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Removing mfcj430wcupswrapper:i386 (3.0.0-1) ...
>
> [ ok ] Restarting cups (via systemctl): cups.service.
>
> Purging configuration files for mfcj430wcupswrapper:i386 (3.0.0-1) ...
>   dpkg-deb: building package 'mfcj430wlpr' in 'mfcj430wlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb'.
>   dpkg -b ./brother_driver_packdir mfcj430wlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
>   dpkg-deb: building package 'mfcj430wcupswrapper' in 'mfcj430wcupswrapper-3.0.0-1a.i386.deb'.
>   dpkg -b ./brother_driver_packdir mfcj430wcupswrapper-3.0.0-1a.i386.deb
>   dpkg -i --force-all mfcj430wlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
>   (Reading database ... 47002 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack mfcj430wlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb ...
>   Unpacking mfcj430wlpr:i386 (3.0.1-1) over (3.0.1-1) ...
>   Setting up mfcj430wlpr:i386 (3.0.1-1) ...
>   dpkg -i --force-all mfcj430wcupswrapper-3.0.0-1a.i386.deb
>   Selecting previously unselected package mfcj430wcupswrapper:i386.
>   (Reading database ... 47002 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack mfcj430wcupswrapper-3.0.0-1a.i386.deb ...
>   Unpacking mfcj430wcupswrapper:i386 (3.0.0-1) ...
>   Setting up mfcj430wcupswrapper:i386 (3.0.0-1) ...
>
> Stopping printer spooler: lpd [not running]
>
> Restarting cups (via systemctl): cups.service.
>
> lpadmin -p MFCJ430W -E -v usb://Brother/MFC-J430W?serial=BROC2F220236 -P /usr/share/cups/model/Brother/brother_mfcj430w_printer_en.ppd
>
> Will you specify the Device URI? [Y/n] ->n
>
> Test Print? [y/N] ->y
>
> wait 5s.
>   lpr -P MFCJ430W /usr/share/cups/data/testprint
>   lpr: connect: No such file or directory
>   Is lpd daemon running?
>   jobs queued, but cannot start daemon.

I have been trying to follow this tutorial: https://davesteele.github.io/raspberrypi/2016/04/23/raspberry-pi-cloudprint/

Comment: Please add the tag "printing". How do you run the installer? pitfall: "When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?", For USB Users: Choose N(No)"

Comment: @Fabian thanks, I updated the post to reflect the changes. Also added the installer output, and I haven't been specifying the DeviceURI.